# Navigation bar jquery technique to replace div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using the following to update a container div in my core html template. It uses the id of the navigation bar element clicked to change the content. I'm new to front end in general - i have created the following but it doesn't seem very robust - what is the generally accepted way of doing this...

javascript file:

```
$(".home").on('click','*', function (event) {
var page = $(this).attr('id');
var pageHtmlLink;

switch(page){
    case "homeButton":
        pageHtmlLink = "Home.html";
        break;
    case "aboutButton":
        pageHtmlLink = "About.html";
        break;
    case "storageButton":
        pageHtmlLink = "Storage.html";
        break;
    case "requestsButton":
        pageHtmlLink = "Requests.html";
        break;
    default:
        pageHtmlLink = "Home.html";
        break;
    }
$.get(pageHtmlLink, function(data){
    $(".container").html(data);
});
});
```

Comment: If the ID will always be `desired  link + "Button"` then you could do: `var pageHtmlLink = page.replace("Button", "") + ".html";` Or, you could put a `data-attribute` on your elements that specifies the page from which they should grab data, and use that instead of ID.

Comment: There's a ton of different ways to do things. But in this case, as long as it works, great. Don't over think it.

Comment: $(".container").load(pageHtmlLink);

Comment: **Voting to close:** This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/